# What @withparser method in Python means?

Tags: python

I wonder if someone can explain what a @withparser method in python does? if I see @withparser before a method what does it mean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be more specific, pleas show us the code of the function `withparser()`, wherever it is defined. It seems to be something project-specific; nothing from the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a decorator see http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators for more infos. It's like a "wrapper" for your function

Answer (score 1):

It's a decorator. More info - http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808